# Why Doesn't `Data(count:)` Allocate Memory In Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to understand how memory allocation and deallocation works in Swift. I wrote this simple loop:

```
func overloadMemory() {
  var data: [Data] = []

  for _ in 0..<100 {
    let datum = Data(count: 10_000_000)
    data.append(datum)
    print("data: \(data.count)")
  }
}
```

I would expect this to allocate 10MB * 100 = 1GB of memory. But when I monitor the memory usage, the loop runs but it doesn't show any change in memory at all. Is there another way to allocate a fixed amount of memory in Swift? Or am I misunderstanding something about `Data`?

Comment: The "as if" principle of optimization compiles doesn't concern itself with preserving run time or memory use. To the contrary, the whole point of optimization compilers is to reduce the run time, memory use, program size, or some trade-off of those 3 factors. In this case, `data` is provably unused, so the optimizer is culling the array, seeing that the `Data` allocation does nothing, culls the allocation, sees the loop is empty, cullS the loop, sees the function is empty, and probably even culls it. In essence, all this code disappears under optimization.

Comment: Thank you! That explains why I wasn't seeing a memory spike at all while running this. Is there any documentation or somewhere I could learn more about how these optimizations work or what gets removed during optimization?

Comment: Not that I know of in particular, but it wouldn't make much sense to concern yourself with the particular optimizations done. Old ones can be removed (if they no longer pay off), and new ones are built all the time. The general principle is that a well-behaved compiler should optimize things such that the optimized program acts "as if" nothing was changed, with regards to the programs behavior (but not its resource use).

Answer (score 3):

How are you measuring the memory usage? Using Instruments, we can see that the memory is being allocated.

[image: Allocations in instruments]
There is a small problem with the code: the `data` variable will be out of scope as soon as the method ends and it will be released.

To test it, I did a small app with a button that performed the allocations, like below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var data: [Data] = []

    @IBAction func overloadMemory() {
      for _ in 0..<100 {
        let datum = Data(count: 10_000_000)
        data.append(datum)
        print("data: \(data.count)")
      }
    }
}
```

In the screenshot, I tapped the button twice and you can see the increase in the allocation

Comment: I was looking at the "Memory Report" panel (screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/bWXvaC4). I'm intentionally not storing `data` anywhere, I'm trying to see how the memory use spikes just within that function call and was surprised to not see a spike in the screenshot I shared above.

Comment: Yeah, I was a little surprised as well. But Instruments gives a better view :)